# Unable to search with keyword in State/Region at Tax Zones and Rates section?

Tags: magento2, tax, table-rates

I am facing one small issue with the "Tax Zones and Rates", while searching with the keyword in the "State/Region" field.

first i have removed rule as shown in the screen shot 1) https://prnt.sc/jwkidj

Then i have removed Tax Zones and Rates 2) https://prnt.sc/jwkiph

getting an error while searching with the any keyword 3) https://prnt.sc/jwkkco

How do i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to reindex and clear magento cache then check it again.

Comment: done but same error getting